# Modal box not showing asp.net

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog

I am trying to get a modal box to show. Whenever I click the button, it fades but the modal box does not show. Does anyone know the problem with my code?

```
asp:Button ID="searchMRF" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary active" Text="Search MRF No." Height="31px" Width="139px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TestModal" />
                                       <%-- MODAL --%>
                                         <div id="TestModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                             <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                 <%-- MODAL CONTENT --%>
                                                 <div class="modal-content">
                                                     <div class="modal-header">
                                                         <asp:Button ID="close1" class="close" Text="x" runat="server" />
                                                         <asp:Label class="modal-title" runat="server" Text="TESTING"></asp:Label>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="modal-body">
                                                         <asp:Label runat="server" class="modal-lg"></asp:Label>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="modal-footer">
                                                         <asp:Button ID="close2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>                                                
                                        </div>
```

Comment: have you looked in the browser console to see if there are any errors

Comment: hmmm I've done a bit of checking. not sure if it sounds wierd but whenever i stop the program from running on the page. when i touch the button (while the program is not running ) thats when the modal box appears but when i run the program it doesnt. wierd. .___.

Comment: Try to add script on button click trigger to show the modal, e.g. `$('<%= searchMRF.ClientID %>').click(function () { $('#TestModal').modal('show'); })`.